# Integrate and NIntegrate not the same

Tags: numerical-integration

Why am I getting two different results here?

```
x0 = -1.01416292;
a = 2.84082292;
b = 0.39397473;
f[x_] := (Log[x] - x0)^(a - 1) Exp[-(Log[x] - x0)/b]/(b^a*Gamma[a] x);
Integrate[f[x], {x, Exp[x0], 10}]
NIntegrate[f[x], {x, Exp[x0], 10}]

(* 1.14436 *)
(* 0.992038 *)
```

I'm pretty sure the [`NIntegrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NIntegrate.html) result is the correct one, since it's a probability distribution and it shouldn't be greater than 1.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using approximate numbers (e.g. ones with decimal points) can lead to issues with exact solvers such as `Integrate`.  One way around, if the function can be integrated with symbolic parameters, is to use `Block` to block the numeric values from being substituted until after the integration is complete:

```
Block[{x0, a, b},
 Assuming[a > 0 && b > 0 && x0 < Log[10],
  Integrate[f[x], {x, Exp[x0], 10}]
  ]]
(*  0.992038  *)
```

One can confirm the numeric issue by using arbitrary precision numbers for the parameters:

```
x0 = -1.01416292`16;
a = 2.84082292`16;
b = 0.39397473`16;
Integrate[f[x], {x, Exp[x0], 10}]
(*  1.14435621208982531824685420020762304511`0.6569554175313712  *)
```

The result has a precision of less than `1.`, which shows that the `1.14` is a close enough approximation at that (horrible) precision.  (The result represents a real number between `0.892` and `1.396`.)

Comment: Note that evaluating the integral without defining `x0`, `a`, and `b` (resulting in `1 - Gamma[a, (Log[10]-x0)/b]/Gamma[a]`), then substituting in the numerical values leads to the correct result (the same as, to 14 decimal places, the result of `NIntegrate`) .

Comment: @Ivan You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's a bug, integrating to [`Infinity`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Infinity.html) yields the correct result of `1.`:

```
Integrate[f[x], {x, Exp[x0], Infinity}]
(* 1. *)
```

Also, I think it's also a part of the possible issues for definite integrals, listed in the [`Integrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integrate.html):

```
eq = Integrate[f[x], x];
(eq /. {x -> 10}) - (eq /. {x -> Exp[x0]})
(* 0.992038 *)
```